# Convert CSV to Excel gives file corrupted error

Tags: excel, perl, export-to-excel

I converted multiple csv files into a excel spreadsheet using the perl script below which is basically a modified version of the code in the [link](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.39/examples/csv2xls.pl), but i cannot open the output excel file, it gives a pop up message "The file is corrupted."

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl -W

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big;
use Text::CSV_XS;

# Check for valid number of arguments
if (($#ARGV < 1) || ($#ARGV > 2)) {
   die("Usage: csv2xls csvfile_dir xlsfile\n");
};

my $csvdir  = $ARGV[0];
my $outfile = $ARGV[1];


# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Big->new($outfile);
my $csvfile   = "";
my $tab_title = "";

foreach $csvfile (glob("$csvdir/*.csv")) {
    print "$csvfile\n";
    # Open the Comma Separated Variable file
    open (CSVFILE, $csvfile) or die "$csvfile: $!";
    $csvfile =~ s/.*\///;
    $tab_title = (split(/\./,$csvfile))[0];
    print "-D- $tab_title\n";

    # Create a new Excel worksheet
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($tab_title);

    # Create a new CSV parsing object
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;

    # Row and column are zero indexed
    my $row = 0;

    while (<CSVFILE>) {
        if ($csv->parse($_)) {
            my @Fld = $csv->fields;
            print "-D- @Fld\n";
            my $col = 0;
            foreach my $token (@Fld) {
                $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
                $col++;
            }
            $row++;
        } else {
            my $err = $csv->error_input;
            print "Text::CSV_XS parse() failed on argument: ", $err, "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your workbook.

```
$workbook->close();
```

Also upgrade your Excel module to the latest version, I also faced the similar issue of corrupted excel files which was solved on updating `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`.

Also from [docs](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/docs/WriteExcel.html)

> Note about the requirement for binmode(). An Excel file is comprised
>   of binary data. Therefore, if you are using a filehandle you should
>   ensure that you binmode() it prior to passing it to new().You should
>   do this regardless of whether you are on a Windows platform or not.
>   This applies especially to users of perl 5.8 on systems where UTF-8 is
>   likely to be in operation such as RedHat Linux 9. If your program,
>   either intentionally or not, writes UTF-8 data to a filehandle that is
>   passed to new() it will corrupt the Excel file that is created.